# -ln links to wrong file

Tags: command-line, bash, matlab

I've just installed matlab and want to be able to call it from the terminal. It works fine when I explicitly call it from its directory.

I cd to

```
/usr/local/bin
```

and type

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab matlab
```

when I then type "matlab" in the terminal, I get the error message "bash: /media/OS/MATLAB/bin/matlab: No such file or directory"

I have no idea why it's trying to call matlab from /media. I've tried deleting the file from usr/local/bin but when I create it again the same thing happens. Any help would be very much appreciated.

EDIT: I have discovered the problem: in a previous install I had added the line

```
alias matlab="/media/OS/MATLAB/bin/matlab"
```

to my `bashrc` file. This has been changed to the correct directory and the problem has been fixed.

Comment: post the output of `which matlab`. From that you can be able to identify the root cause of the problem.

Comment: What is the purpose of the symbolic link? Why are you trying to create it?

Comment: @Avinash /usr/local/bin/matlab

Comment: @Jobin So I don't have to cd to the directory to use it. I use it a lot.

Comment: Which directory do you go to for starting matlab?

Comment: @Jobin /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin

Comment: post the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin/matlab`

Comment: @Avinash lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 Jun  7 01:28 /usr/local/bin/matlab -> /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab

Comment: @user289075 Whats the output of `ls -l /usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab`?

Comment: @dan08 Problem solved, see my edit. Silly mistake on my part. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead create an alias instead of a symbolic link, so that it keeps your system clean and prevent unnecessary binaries from filling it up.

Open your `~/.bash_aliases` file and paste the following (don't worry if its empty, it will be empty if you have not aliases any commands before using this file):

```
alias matlab='/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012a/bin/matlab'
```

save the file and exit and then do

```
source ~/.bash_aliases
```

from a terminal and then you should be able to type

```
matlab
```

and get matlab working.

Comment: Cool. Just to clarify, I will first need to type `source ~/.bash_aliases` every time I want to use matlab?

Comment: Thanks for your help Jobin, I realised what the problem was: at some point in time I had added `alias matlab="/media/OS/MATLAB/bin/matlab"` to my `bashrc` file (in a previous install, I believe). I have changed this alias the correct directory, to avoid calling `source` every time I want to use matlab. Is this fine to do?

Comment: @user289075: First, it is better to have all aliases in one file and that is the purpose of `~/.bash_aliases` and secondly, you don't have to source everytime, just once after you modify the file having the alias.

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm. Thanks for your help.